# VBA working in one macro excel properly but not in other macro excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a vba code to find match in dynamic column "F" with cell value i cell "i1". And when match found in the column " F" it will clear the content of the particular row.
The VBA is working fine in the excel marco where I have written the VBA code but to my surprise when I copy the same VBA code to a different excel macro having the same content in worksheet and run the VBA code it does not clear all the match content row i.e., it clear some of the match row leaving some of match row uncleared. Where I am doing the mistake?

```
Sub test()

    Dim i as long

    For i = 100 To 1 step -1
        If Range("F" & i).Value = Range("i1").Value Then Rows(i).EntireRow.ClearContent
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Picture of the macro excel worksheet]

Comment: You are iterating from 100 to 1... is your range >100 rows in the new workbook?

Comment: also, *Range("i1").Value* looks funny, since you have i as your variable... just make that upper case, if you are truly intending to use cells(1,"I").  might make it a little easier to review as such

Comment: Do you really use the code above. It contains a typo or "Copy&Paste" bug: `Rows(i).EntireRow.ClearContents`

Comment: Yes I have done this (1,"I") but still not working..... Moreover, I have tested with different VBA code but the same problem persisted.

Comment: No no, there is no typo error. Otherwise, the code would not execute properly.

Comment: There is a typo! Can't you read? Code will fail as soon as the if condition becomes true

Comment: @Storax brief the typo you're suggesting..

Comment: There is a typo in the post of the TO!

Comment: @DavidZemens `ClearContent` is missing an "s"

Comment: The typo would raise a compile error. The macro *cannot possibly execute* until that is rectified. Since OP suggests the macro *is actually executing*, this may be a transposition/copy/paste error here on Stack Overflow. I think OP needs to clarify what nature of the problem is.

Comment: No, the typo does not raise a compile error! It will only error out at run time telling object does not support this mehtod or property.

Comment: Ah right, 438. In any case, OP still suggests that this *partially* works. So, I think probably the typo not exist in his actual code, only here on SO. We need OP to clarify.

Comment: @dibyendu I think you must provide some example data. Are you sure the values are exactly equal (with no leading/trailing spaces, or, dates versus strings that *look like dates*,e tc.)? You need to step through code using F8 and breakpoint to identify when the condition is not met, but you think it should be met. Then you will able to see why it is a discrepancy.

Comment: @David Zemens, the string here is date. And the date is  placed in the column and the cell by VBA macro calendar. So I don't think there will be formatting errors.

Comment: A string isn't a date and you should not rely on implicit type conversions when comparing dates and strings. Since you haven't provided example data, and nobody knows what your "vba macro calendar" actually does, it's not really possible to help you much further until you do so.

Comment: I have provided example data(picture) by editing my question. Please have a look as it may help to express by problem

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you just have to fix your typo and copy the code into a module (not the worksheet or workbook module) and it will work on the active sheet.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
    For i = 100 To 1 Step -1
        If Range("F" & i).Value = Range("i1").Value Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: But I assume that it was not a typo error. Otherwise, it would not work properly in the macro excel. Moreover, when I copied the VBA code to different excel macro it is clearing some of the matched rows.

Comment: If it is not a typo and your code is running in other workbooks you have to provide sample data.

Comment: OP provided incomplete / non working code. There's no way what he pasted in OP actually worked. +1 for fixing it. No need to explain why it "it works in one workbook and not another" because no working code was presented.

Comment: @ Storax, I have added a picture of sample data by updating by question. Please have a look

Comment: You added a picture not sample data

Answer (score 1):

`Rows(i)` and `Range("F" & i)` is defined implicitly which might refer to another sheet or even another workbook.

below is a sample code with use of sheet reference.

```
Dim i as long
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("YourSheetName")
For i = 100 To 1 step -1 
    If ws.Range("F" & i).Value = ws.Range("i1").Value Then ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.ClearContents
Next i
```

Comment: If there is any other ways to do so through VBA coding

Comment: @SJR 12, you are correct. It is working properly in one excel but when I copied it is clearing some of the matched rows but not all matched found.